# Azure Service bus queue data receiver

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-stream-analytics, azure-queues

I have following ProcessQueueMessage function that gathers messages from service bus queue:

```
    public static void ProcessQueueMessage([ServiceBusTrigger("dsique2")] BrokeredMessage message,
        TextWriter logger)
    {
        logger.WriteLine($"Processing message: {message}");
        Stream stream = message.GetBody<Stream>();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
        string s = reader.ReadToEnd();
        //Parse json
        string output = s.Substring(s.IndexOf('{') , s.IndexOf('}') - s.IndexOf('{') + 1);
         var  json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(output);
         var TS = Convert.ToDouble(json.ts);
         var Speed = Convert.ToDouble(json.speed);
         var Ped = Convert.ToDouble(json.ped);
         var BrakePed = Convert.ToDouble(json.brakeped);
         var lateralAcc1 = Convert.ToDouble(json.lateralacc1);
         var steeringAngle = Convert.ToDouble(json.steeringangle);
         //sends parsed values to function 
         Program.receive_emulate(0x415, Speed, TS, "offlineSpeed");
         Program.receive_emulate(0x204, BrakePed , TS, "BrakePed ");
         Program.receive_emulate(0x7D, lateralAcc1 , TS, "lateralAcc1 ");
         Program.receive_emulate(0x92, steeringAngle , TS, "steeringAngle ");
}
```

So basically, whenever data comes from service bus queue as json format, I parse the json, get values and sent each signals to receive_emulate function. The problem is that the function is triggered before the data processing in receive_emulate function ends. What I want to do is, process single message, send them to receive_emulate functions. When function returns, take the second message in the queue. Unfortunately I could not achive this, any ideas would be deeply appreciated.
Another even though it is written that Fifo is guaranteed in service bus queues in azure documentation, I notice that my messages are not coming in order. Is there any way to get them in ordered form?
Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I read your code correctly, you are using Azure Functions with Service Bus trigger.

Try setting `maxConcurrentCalls` parameter to `1` in `hosts.json` file, which is shown [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/wiki/host.json).

> The maximum number of concurrent calls to the callback the message
>   pump should initiate. The default is 16.

Comment: Sorted out. Thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

Just like @Mikhail pointed out, setting concurrency to one will allow you to process your messages in serial way either via [host.json](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/wiki/host.json) you can

I'll focus on your second question about FIFO. Azure Service Bus does **not** guarantee order of messages, unless you're using [Messaging Sessions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-azure-and-service-bus-queues-compared-contrasted#foundational-capabilities). As far as I know, Service Bus sessions are [not currently supported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus) with Functions.

Comment: Indeed, lack of session support in Functions is a big problem for us...